# Monogame rotating a sprite

Tags: c#, monogame, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a sprite in Monogame, but for some reason I can't get it right! I would be really grateful if someone explains the mystery of rotation!

This is the line of code that I am using to draw and rotate my sprite, just a note the variable `rotation` is the angle I am incrementing it by 0.1 on every Update, this is just for testing purpose. How do I make the cannon rotate around an origin point that is inside the image? For example around its center point like a helicopter propeller? [Check the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9ilpyegCWQ) to see the result from this line of code.

```
        spriteBatch.Draw(cannon.image, new Rectangle(300, 300, cannon.image.Width, cannon.image.Height), null, Color.White, rotation, new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like the overload you're using:

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     float scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

The problem is that you need to set the origin point to rotate around. In MonoGame / XNA the origin is specified in pixels relative to the size of the texture. So to calculate the centre of the sprite you need to do something like this:

```
var origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2f, texture.Height / 2f);
```

Then call the sprite batch draw method like so:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(cannon.image, new Rectangle(300, 300, cannon.image.Width, cannon.image.Height), null, Color.White, y, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Lastly, please don't use `y` as the variable name for rotation, it could be very confusing for another programmer reading your code. A better name would be `rotation`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem indeed, I wasn't setting the correct origin point. As far as the y variable, it was just for testing purposes. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you sorted it out yourself. I thought it was worth explaining the details. Please mark the answer as accepted. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Answer: in the new Vector2(x, y) I just had to set x and y values that are within the image.

Comment: You should mark the answer of @craftworkgames as the accepted answer and not mention it as your own answer and accept it!